# Json Decode,Access, show and separate names with ID, every 9 names

Tags: php, arrays, json, decode

Hello :) I give you the Json Decode below.
http://pastebin.com/XqhTMWCS

It presents my last 10 games. I need to get my 4 teamates for every game,and my 5 enemies.(names) **When someone is a teamate, his "teamId" is 100 and when someone is an enemy,the "teamId" is 200**. I need to separate and show them.

Like: You were playing Vayne. Your team was:

> sirjack1101 playing champion ID 89
>
> blablaa playing ID 22
>
> blablaaa playing ID 23
>
> blablaaaa playing ID 24

The enemy team was:

> blablsaa playing ID 31
>
> bsadaaas playing ID 12
>
> basdasdb playing ID 53
>
> blablsad playing ID 67
>
> blablsav playing ID 121

I can find only the first username using this :

```
$recent = "My json" ;
$rec    = file_get_contents($recent);
$recdat = json_decode($rec, true); 
$fellow = $recdat[gameStatistics][0][fellowPlayers][0][summonerName];
echo $fellow;
```

And I can get only my 1st champion name using the same code... I need your help! :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a pastebin for the JSON itself? It will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need a `foreach` loop to iterate over all players.

```
<?php
define('TEAMMATE_ID', 100);
define('ENEMY_ID', 200);

$teammates = $enemies = array();
foreach ($data['gameStatistics'][0]['fellowPlayers'] as $player) {
  if ($player['teamId'] == TEAMMATE_ID) {
    $teammates[] = $player['summonerName'] .' playing ID '. $player['championId'];
  }
  else if ($player['teamId'] == ENEMY_ID) {
    $enemies[] = $player['summonerName'] .' playing ID '. $player['championId'];
  }
}

// List of teammates.
print "Teammates:\n";
print implode("\n", array_slice($teammates, 0, 4));

// List of enemies.
print "Enemies:\n";
print implode("\n", array_slice($enemies, 0, 5));
?>
```

Hopefully I'm not way off base...

Comment: Note that if no game will have more than four teammates and five enemies you can remove the calls to `array_slice()` :-)